# Symfony2 dropdown from entity and session variable set

Tags: php, symfony, drop-down-menu, form-submit

I have an entity which defines the clients for each user (they have they own CRUD for this).

I need to create a dropdown in the header where the user can select the client to work with, and this must set a session variable with the ID (like setting a profile to work with). This must be a self submit dropdown.

Any clues on how to achieve that?.

Right now the clients entity is pretty simple so I'll not post it here. The name is 'Clients', the field to be used is 'id' and it has another field 'owner' which has relation with the user table.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: You can achieve this using jquery. On change event of client drop down call ajax request with that selected client id and in controller ajaxAction set that id in symfony session.

Comment: That part is easy :) I meant on how to achieve the dropdown from entity and how to set the symfony session variable.

Comment: Than want you want can't got properly without sample code.